# C++ corresponding decode function to rsa.EncryptOAEP() in Golang

Tags: c++, go, openssl, rsa

I am working on implementing communication protocol between a client in c++ and server in golang.

A shared secret need to be encrypted by rsa in golang server, using the public key provided by c++ client. Client in c++ need to use the private key to decrypt and get the shared secret.

Currently I am using [EncryptOAEP](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#EncryptOAEP) to encrypt the secret in golang. And decrypt message with [RSA_private_decrypt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rsa_private_decrypt) and padding using `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` provided by openssl. However this does not convert the encrypted secret back to plain text.

Is there any other rsa decrypted function I need to use to decrypt the cyphertext from golang? Thanks in advance.

Note: prefered function from libcrypto version 1.1

Comment: You don't show any code, so we don't know what parameters you are supplying. A look at the docs for each shows that Go recommends using sha256 but openssl defaults to sha1. Try using sha1 in the Go program. Note that although SHA1 is deprecated, its use in OAEP is still considered secure. It would be better though to find a way to use SHA256 in the C++ code.

Comment: @James K Polk very appreciate for your tips. I tried to change the hash function to use sha1 in golang and that makes the decryption works! I'll continue to search around to see if sha256 is possible to be used in c++. Thank you!